# JQUERY hide IMG tag when src path is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know we shouldn't have `img` tags without a `src` path, but this is the code I'm stuck with trouble shooting. I've tried a few different forms of Javascript and JQUERY, but I'm still learning. I've used all of the other links on stackoverflow that were specifically for hiding images without src paths, but none have helped. I mixed a few of them and this script is the closest I could get to work with dynamic images (The images are being called out dynamically)

HTML:

```
<div class="item"><img src="{{imgMain}}" alt="" id="imgOne"/></div>
<div class="item"><img src="{{imgTwo}}" alt="" id="imgTwo"/></div>
<div class="item"><img src="{{imgThree}}" alt="" id="imgThree"/></div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $(img).each(function(){    
    if ($(this).attr("src") === "_")         
      $(this).remove(); 
    else        
      $(this).addClass("show"); 
  });     
});
```

Comment: so if it is empty, why are you checking for "_"?

Answer (score 1):

register the onload event on img tag :)

```js
function showOnLoad(e){
  e.target.style.display = "inline";
}
```

```css
.hide{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img class="hide" onload="showOnLoad(event)" src="http://coolwildlife.com/wp-content/uploads/galleries/post-3004/Fox%20Picture%20003.jpg" />
<img class="hide" onload="showOnLoad()" src="" />
<div id="result" > </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="item"><img src="something" alt="" id="imgOne" class="x" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="something" alt="" id="imgTwo" class="x"/></div>
<div class="item"><img src="_" alt="" id="imgThree" class="x"/></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $('.x').each(function(){    

 if ($(this).attr("src") === "_")         
   $(this).remove(); 
 else        
    $(this).addClass("show"); 
  });     
 });   
</script>
```